# dependencies problem with installing wine-32-stable and i386 packages Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

I was trying to install winehq on my **Ubuntu 20.04** and came up with a lot of dependency errors. after trying to install each dependeny and getting help from aptitude, I encountered a huge problem. If I want to install packages `libicu66:i386 libutempter0 libxml2:i386 xterm`, almost my whole packages are going to get removed. This is what I get:

```
 sudo apt install --reinstall libicu66:i386 libutempter0 libxml2:i386 xterm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  blt cabextract dctrl-tools digikam-data dkms duplicity enchant-2 fig2dev folks-common fonts-motoya-l-cedar fonts-roboto-hinted fonts-roboto-unhinted fonts-wine fprintd frei0r-plugins fuseiso
  gconf2-common gdal-data gir1.2-camel-1.2 gir1.2-gee-0.8 gir1.2-graphene-1.0 gir1.2-gsound-1.0 gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 gnome-settings-daemon-common gparted-common guile-2.2-libs icoutils jq
  kdenlive-data kmymoney-common libaec0 libalgorithm-c3-perl libalkimia5-7 libamtk-5-common libaqbanking-data libarmadillo9 libarpack2 libastro1 libasync-mergepoint-perl libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libavresample4
  libb-hooks-endofscope-perl libb-hooks-op-check-perl libblas3 libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libcamel-1.2-62 libcapi20-3 libcapture-tiny-perl libchafa0 libcharls2 libclass-c3-perl libclass-c3-xs-perl
  libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-inspector-perl libclass-method-modifiers-perl libclass-singleton-perl libclass-xsaccessor-perl libcodec2-0.9 libcommon-sense-perl libcpanel-json-xs-perl libcue2
  libdata-optlist-perl libdatetime-format-strptime-perl libdatetime-locale-perl libdatetime-perl libdatetime-timezone-perl libdevel-callchecker-perl libdevel-caller-perl libdevel-lexalias-perl
  libdevel-size-perl libdevel-stacktrace-perl libdynaloader-functions-perl libebur128-1 libenchant-2-2 libepsilon1 libept1.6.0 libeval-closure-perl libexception-class-perl libexempi8
  libfile-find-rule-perl libfile-sharedir-perl libfinance-quote-perl libfolks25 libfont-ttf-perl libfprint-2-2 libfreexl1 libfuture-perl libfyba0 libgavl1 libgconf-2-4 libgdcm3.0 libgeos-3.8.0
  libgeos-c1v5 libgeotiff5 libglew2.1 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libgrantlee-textdocument5 libgsf-1-common libgsl23 libgslcblas0 libgsoap-2.8.91 libgsound0 libgtksourceview-4-common libgwengui-cpp0
  libgwengui-qt5-0 libgwenhywfar-data libgwenhywfar79 libhdf4-0-alt libhdf5-103 libhtml-tableextract-perl libimport-into-perl libio-async-loop-epoll-perl libio-async-perl libjq1 libjson-maybexs-perl
  libjson-parse-perl libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl libkchart2 libkchart2-l10n libkf5akonadi-data libkf5akonadicontact-data libkf5akonadicore-bin libkf5akonadiprivate5abi2 libkf5calendarcore5abi2
  libkf5identitymanagement-data libkf5mediaplayer-data libkf5mime-data libkf5mime5abi2 libkf5pimtextedit-data libkmlbase1 libkmldom1 libkmlengine1 liblapack3 liblensfun-data-v1 liblensfun1
  liblinux-epoll-perl liblist-compare-perl liblzf1 libmarblewidget-qt5-28 libmaxminddb0 libminiupnpc17 libmlt-data libmodplug1 libmodule-implementation-perl libmodule-runtime-perl libmoo-perl
  libmoox-aliases-perl libmovit8 libmro-compat-perl libmspack0 libnamespace-autoclean-perl libnamespace-clean-perl libnetcdf15 libnumber-compare-perl libodbc1 libofx7 libogdi4.1 libonig5
  libopencv-core4.2 libopencv-flann4.2 libopencv-imgproc4.2 libopencv-ml4.2 libopusfile0 libosmesa6 libosp5 libpackage-stash-perl libpackage-stash-xs-perl libpadwalker-perl libpam-fprintd
  libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libpangox-1.0-0 libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl libparams-validationcompiler-perl libpath-tiny-perl libpkcs11-helper1 libpotrace0 libpq5 libproj15 libpython2-stdlib
  libqhull7 libqt5serialport5 libreadonly-perl libref-util-perl libref-util-xs-perl libreoffice-style-elementary librole-tiny-perl librsync2 librttr-core0.9.6 libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0
  libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 libsereal-decoder-perl libsereal-encoder-perl libsereal-perl libshp2 libsocket++1 libsox-fmt-alsa libsox-fmt-base libsox3 libspecio-perl libsqlcipher0 libstb0 libstrictures-perl
  libstruct-dumb-perl libsub-exporter-perl libsub-exporter-progressive-perl libsub-identify-perl libsub-install-perl libsub-quote-perl libsuperlu5 libsz2 libtbb2 libtelepathy-glib0 libtest-fatal-perl
  libtest-refcount-perl libtext-glob-perl libtext-template-perl libtype-tiny-perl libtype-tiny-xs-perl libtypes-serialiser-perl libunicode-utf8-perl liburiparser1 libuv1 libvariable-magic-perl libvkd3d1
  libvncserver1 libwmf-bin libwxbase3.0-0v5 libxerces-c3.2 libxml-writer-perl libxstring-perl libxvidcore4 marble-plugins marble-qt-data network-manager-openvpn odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 opencv-data
  openjdk-8-jdk-headless openvpn oxygen-icon-theme proj-bin proj-data python-backports.functools-lru-cache python-bs4 python-chardet python-gi python-html5lib python-numpy python-pkg-resources
  python-pygame-sdl2 python-six python-soupsieve python-tk python-webencodings python-wxversion python2 python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal python3-dateutil python3-future python3-lockfile
  python3-paramiko recordmydesktop scrcpy-server switcheroo-control tk8.6-blt2.5 virtualbox-dkms xdg-dbus-proxy
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  xfonts-cyrillic
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  adwaita-icon-theme aisleriot anydesk appmenu-gtk3-module apport-gtk appstream apt-config-icons apt-config-icons-hidpi apt-config-icons-large apt-config-icons-large-hidpi apturl ark avahi-daemon
  avahi-utils baloo-kf5 baobab bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs bluedevil breeze breeze-gtk-theme chafa cheese chrome-gnome-shell colord dconf-editor debconf-kde-helper deja-dup digikam
  digikam-private-libs dnsutils dolphin drkonqi dvdauthor dvgrab elisa eog evince evolution-data-server fcitx-frontend-gtk2 fcitx-frontend-gtk3 fcitx-module-x11 fcitx-mozc fcitx-ui-classic ffmpeg
  ffmpegthumbs file-roller filelight firefox frameworkintegration fwupd fwupd-signed fwupdate gconf-service gconf-service-backend gcr gdm3 gedit geoclue-2.0 gettext gir1.2-clutter-1.0
  gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-ebookcontacts-1.2 gir1.2-edataserver-1.2 gir1.2-folks-0.6 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-geoclue-2.0
  gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gtksource-4 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-handy-0.0
  gir1.2-mutter-6 gir1.2-nautilus-3.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0
  gir1.2-vte-2.91 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gjs gkbd-capplet gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-calendar gnome-characters gnome-clocks gnome-control-center gnome-dictionary
  gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-getting-started-docs-fa gnome-getting-started-docs-ja gnome-initial-setup gnome-keyring gnome-logs gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines
  gnome-online-accounts gnome-power-manager gnome-screenshot gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
  gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect-browsers gnome-shell-extension-prefs gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-startup-applications
  gnome-sudoku gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-themes-extra gnome-todo gnome-tweak-tool gnome-tweaks gnome-user-docs gnome-user-docs-fa gnome-user-docs-ja gnome-user-guide gnome-video-effects
  gnustep-base-runtime google-chrome-stable gparted grilo-plugins-0.3-base gstreamer-qapt gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-packagekit gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
  gtk-update-icon-cache gtk2-engines-murrine gtk2-engines-pixbuf gvfs-backends gwenview hplip humanity-icon-theme ibus ibus-data ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 ibus-mozc ibus-table imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16
  inkscape intltool-debian ippusbxd kaccounts-integration kaccounts-providers kactivitymanagerd kamera kate kcalc kde-cli-tools kde-config-fcitx kde-config-gtk-style kde-config-gtk-style-preview
  kde-config-screenlocker kde-config-sddm kde-config-tablet kde-config-whoopsie kde-spectacle kde-style-breeze kde-style-oxygen-qt5 kdeconnect kded5 kdegraphics-thumbnailers kdenetwork-filesharing
  kdenlive kdialog kdoctools5 keditbookmarks kgamma5 khelpcenter khotkeys kinfocenter kinit kio kio-audiocd kio-extras kmahjongg kmenuedit kmines kmplayer kmymoney kolourpaint konsole konsole-kpart
  konversation kpackagelauncherqml kpackagetool5 kpat kpeople-vcard krdc kross kscreen ksshaskpass ksudoku ksysguard ksystemlog ktexteditor-katepart ktorrent kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-notification-helper
  kubuntu-settings-desktop kwalletmanager kwin-addons kwin-common kwin-style-breeze kwin-x11 kwrited language-selector-gnome libabw-0.1-1 libaccounts-glib0 libaccounts-qt5-1 libamtk-5-0
  libappindicator3-1 libappmenu-gtk3-parser0 libappstream-glib8 libappstream4 libappstreamqt2 libaqbanking44 libarchive13 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58
  libbluray2 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libchromaprint1 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcmis-0.5-5v5
  libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libcolorcorrect5 libcolord-gtk1 libcroco3 libdap25 libdapclient6v5 libdazzle-1.0-0 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libdebconf-kde1 libdmapsharing-3.0-2
  libe-book-0.1-1 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-24 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libepub0 libetonyek-0.1-1
  libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 libfaudio0 libfile-mimeinfo-perl libfolks-eds25 libfwupdplugin1 libgail-3-0 libgail-common libgail18 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdal26 libgdata22 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgeoclue-2-0 libgeocode-glib0 libgnome-autoar-0-0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-desktop-3-17 libgnome-desktop-3-19 libgnome-games-support-1-3 libgnomekbd8 libgnustep-base1.26
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgphoto2-6 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgrilo-0.3-0 libgsf-1-114 libgspell-1-1 libgspell-1-2 libgssdp-1.2-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk3-perl
  libgtkglext1 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-4-0 libgtkspell0 libgupnp-1.2-0 libgupnp-av-1.0-2 libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libgweather-3-16 libgxps2 libhandy-0.0-0
  libhfstospell10 libimage-magick-perl libimage-magick-q16-perl libindicator3-7 libjuh-java libjurt-java libkaccounts1 libkf5akonadicontact5abi1 libkf5akonadicore5abi2 libkf5akonadiwidgets5abi1
  libkf5auth5 libkf5authcore5 libkf5baloo5 libkf5baloowidgets-bin libkf5baloowidgets-data libkf5baloowidgets5 libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5cddb5 libkf5compactdisc5 libkf5configwidgets5 libkf5contacteditor5
  libkf5contacts5 libkf5coreaddons5 libkf5crash5 libkf5declarative5 libkf5doctools5 libkf5emoticons-bin libkf5emoticons5 libkf5filemetadata-bin libkf5filemetadata3 libkf5globalaccel-bin
  libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5iconthemes-bin libkf5iconthemes5 libkf5identitymanagement5abi1 libkf5jobwidgets5 libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5kdegames7 libkf5kdegamesprivate1 libkf5kdelibs4support5
  libkf5kdelibs4support5-bin libkf5khtml-bin libkf5khtml5 libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5 libkf5kiogui5 libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5kipi32.0.0 libkf5kmahjongglib5 libkf5krossui5
  libkf5mediaplayer5 libkf5newstuff5 libkf5newstuffcore5 libkf5notifications5 libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5package5 libkf5parts-plugins libkf5parts5 libkf5people5 libkf5peoplewidgets5
  libkf5pimtextedit5abi3 libkf5plasma5 libkf5plasmaquick5 libkf5pty5 libkf5purpose-bin libkf5purpose5 libkf5quickaddons5 libkf5runner5 libkf5sane5 libkf5service-bin libkf5service5 libkf5style5
  libkf5su-bin libkf5su5 libkf5sysguard-bin libkf5texteditor-bin libkf5texteditor5 libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5torrent6 libkf5wallet-bin libkf5wallet5 libkf5webkit5 libkf5xmlgui5 libkpmcore9
  libkscreenlocker5 libksgrd7 libksignalplotter7 libkubuntu1 libkwalletbackend5-5 libkwin4-effect-builtins1 libkwineffects12 libkworkspace5-5 liblangtag1 liblouisutdml-bin liblouisutdml9
  libmagick++-6.q16-8 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libmediaart-2.0-0 libmlt++3 libmlt6 libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libmutter-2-0 libmutter-6-0 libnautilus-extension1a
  libneon27-gnutls libnma0 libnotificationmanager1 libnotify-bin libnotify4 libnss-mdns libokular5core9 libopenconnect5 libopencv-calib3d4.2 libopencv-features2d4.2 libopencv-highgui4.2
  libopencv-imgcodecs4.2 libopencv-objdetect4.2 libopencv-videoio4.2 liboxygenstyle5-5 libpeas-1.0-0 libpowerdevilcore2 libprocesscore7 libprocessui7 libqalculate20 libqapt3-runtime libqt5webengine5
  libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5webenginewidgets5 libqt5webkit5 libqtav1 libqtavwidgets1 libquicktime2 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base-core
  libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-help-common libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-help-ja
  libreoffice-impress libreoffice-kf5 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-l10n-fa libreoffice-l10n-ja libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-plasma
  libreoffice-qt5 libreoffice-writer librest-0.7-0 librhythmbox-core10 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2 libsane libsane1
  libscim8v5 libsnapd-glib1 libsnapd-qt1 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libspatialite7 libstoken1 libtaskmanager6 libtepl-4-0 libtotem-plparser18 libtotem0 libtracker-control-2.0-0
  libtracker-miner-2.0-0 libtracker-sparql-2.0-0 libuno-cppu3 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libvisio-0.1-1 libvoikko1 libvte-2.91-0 libweather-ion7
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwine libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 libxklavier16 libxml-libxml-perl libxml2 libxml2-utils libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss libxslt1.1 libyelp0 light-themes lintian
  melt milou mousetweaks mozc-server muon mutter nautilus nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal nautilus-share network-manager-gnome network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome
  notification-daemon nsight-systems nvidia-visual-profiler okular okular-extra-backends openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre orca packagekit packagekit-tools partitionmanager pavucontrol-qt
  phonon4qt5-backend-vlc pinentry-gnome3 plasma-browser-integration plasma-calendar-addons plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-desktop plasma-discover plasma-discover-backend-fwupd
  plasma-discover-backend-snap plasma-discover-snap-backend plasma-framework plasma-integration plasma-nm plasma-pa plasma-runners-addons plasma-thunderbolt plasma-vault plasma-wallpapers-addons
  plasma-widgets-addons plasma-workspace playonlinux polkit-kde-agent-1 powerdevil print-manager pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth python-lxml python-nautilus python-renpy python-wxgtk3.0
  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-uno qapt-batch qapt-deb-installer qml-module-org-kde-activities qml-module-org-kde-draganddrop qml-module-org-kde-kaccounts qml-module-org-kde-kcm
  qml-module-org-kde-kconfig qml-module-org-kde-kcoreaddons qml-module-org-kde-kio qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons
  qml-module-org-kde-kwindowsystem qml-module-org-kde-newstuff qml-module-org-kde-people qml-module-org-kde-purpose qml-module-org-kde-qqc2desktopstyle qml-module-org-kde-runnermodel
  qml-module-qtwebengine qml-module-qtwebkit qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts qt5-gtk-platformtheme remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-secret remmina-plugin-vnc renpy renpy-demo rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar rhythmbox-plugins rygel sane-utils scrcpy sddm-theme-breeze seahorse shared-mime-info shotwell signon-kwallet-extension signon-ui-x11 simple-scan skanlite
  smbclient software-properties-common software-properties-gtk software-properties-qt sonnet-plugins spice-vdagent synaptic system-config-printer system-config-printer-common systemsettings thermald
  thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-gb thunderbird-locale-en-us thunderbird-locale-fa thunderbird-locale-ja totem totem-plugins tracker tracker-extract
  tracker-miner-fs transmission-gtk ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mono ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-session ubuntu-standard unar uno-libs-private
  update-manager update-notifier ure usb-creator-gtk user-manager vino virtualbox virtualbox-qt vlc vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-video-output wine wine64 winetricks xdg-desktop-portal
  xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xdg-desktop-portal-kde xdg-user-dirs-gtk yaru-theme-gtk yelp zenity
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libicu66:i386 libutempter0 libxml2:i386 xterm
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 696 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 9,339 kB/10.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,354 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Now is there any solution to install wine32 without these huge problems?

Comment: I see *two* problems: 1) All the orphaned packages eligible for autoremoval, and 2) The incompatible wine packages. Fix #1 first, it's easy: `sudo apt autoremove`. Problem #2 commonly occurs when folks try to install new upstream (non-Ubuntu) Wine packages onto an older release of Ubuntu (like 20.04). If that's your problem, then it's also easy to fix: Use the tested, compatible Wine packages in the Ubuntu repositories instead. Also, let the author of your instructions know about the problem you encountered so they will update their instructions. If #2 is NOT the problem, then details please.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I'll tell you the result after trying.